# how to apply css class to the root folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

How shall I apply Css Class to the root folder of my mvc application.Because when the application is not given the name of the controller and the start action it is not displaying the images and the css

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as a "CSS Class" and people use the term to sometimes mean "HTML class" and sometimes mean "CSS rule-set" (and sometimes a "CSS class selector"), but each of those can only be applied to an element, not a "folder".

Answer (score 1):

I think your referring to the reference within link tag in your header?

If this is the case the best solution in my opinion is to use Url.Conent so your link tag will look something like:

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content( "~/Content/Site.css" ) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

That way no matter what the url the user is viewing the reference to the style sheet is always correct.